# Are Algebra and Geometry deeply linked by the complex numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The fact that the rotation matrix of R2 is similar to the product of a complex with another of modulus 1, is an immediate consequence of the geometric representation of complex by a R2-shaped plane, or could mean a deeper connexion between Algebra of equations and Geometry?

Comment: Since complex multiplication corresponds to rotation, the answer is yes.

Comment: The primary link is that the [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry) and the [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) describe the same mathematical entity. Once that's established, using matrices vs. complex numbers for coordinates is merely a choice of representation. Some related questions at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506194/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375912/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316591/).

Comment: Pascal, Descartes and Fermat coordinatized the Euclidean plane in the 17th centory. What I have never been able to understand is why it took 200 years for people to realize that this coordinatization meant that a potint could be defintd as an  ordered pair of real numbers and a line could be defined as a set of points satisfying a linear equation, so $\mathbb R^2$ is a model of Euclidean geometry. Yes, that requires a shift of thinking, but why dtd it take 200 years?!

Comment: However, if i² wasn't defined as -1, the product of complex wouldn't be analogous to the rotation matrix. So, if I'm not overthinking, there could be a further explanation which not only comprises the link between Euclidean plane and Cartesian system, but also the proper link between Cartesian and Complex Algebra.